# How to find the remote-debugging-port of existing Chrome instance

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-remote-debugging

I'm trying to connect to the browser that the Playwright recorder spawns (the one that's created when using `playwright codegen`).

For browsers that have been created with the `--remote-debugging-port` flag, is there a way to see the current debugging URL, or can you only access that URL from stderr when Chrome starts? I've looked through the links at `chrome://about/`, but I couldn't find it.